# Parseable problem cors Policy , api call not working

Tags: javascript, logging, axios

I have a problem while using parseable. I want to send logs from domain x to domain y, but I'm getting an error. Is it possible to disable the core policy?

Access to XMLHttpRequest at '****domainX' from origin 'xxxDOmainY' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I expect the API call to Parseable to work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.